# Estimate size of union of non distinct finite sets which size is only known as an aggregate

Tags: estimation

I have $n$ unknown finite sets $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$. I only know:

- $|A_n| = X_n$
- $ |\cup^n_{x=1}A_x| = X$
- $ |A_x \cup A_y| \leq |A_x| + |A_y|\ with\ x,y \in \{1,...,n\}$

Can I estimate the size of $ \cup^6_{x=0}A_x $ better than using the inequality above.

My current approach would be running a simulation but I would expect a mathematical approach that is simpler and probably a less ad-hoc.

Comment: You mention something about taking the largest sets, so I think you didn't gave all information about your question.

Comment: @Esgeriath what information is missing? Given that I have the individual sizes of the sets, I do know the largest ones? However, I deleted the second part of the question as it is confusing and can be answered by the first part of the question.

Comment: Ahh, sorry you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a probabalistic answer?

Without any additional knowledge about the sets, we assume the elements are random. If all the sets were disjoint then we would have  $|\cup_{x=1}^n A_x|=\sum_{x=1}^n |A_x|:=Y$, that is $X=Y$. But if we have non-empty intersections, then $X<Y$. Hence, we could say, that the probably a random element from a random set will repeat in another set is $\frac{Y-X}{Y}$.

This would then appear to form a binomial calculation based on how large $n$ is and how large each set is. For example, given a set $A$, how much of $A$ will repeat in another set $B$. Well for each element in $A$ the odds it will repeat in any of the sets is $\frac{Y-X}{Y}$, so the odds it will repeat specifically in $B$ is $\frac{Y-X}{Y}\frac{|B|}{Y-|A|}$.

Continuing in this fashion we could find what the expected size of the union of two random sets is. Similarly we could go through the calculations for 3 random sets unioning, and 4, etc.

Comment: Yes! This is what I am looking for. How high is the confidence associated with that estimate? I.e., assuming the probability of an element of A being in B is 30% and A has the size of 100. How likely are 30 in B? I would assume that reducing the number to 20 would increase the confidence of the estimate?

Comment: I haven't worked through all the calculations. But in general, given a collection of N sets, there is some expected joint-wise overlap, such that when combined altogether we end up with on average an overall overlap that gives us a size of X. That is, we should expect that any two sets have a little bit of overlap, even when all combined together we get a lot of overlap. I don't the exact calculation between the two.

Comment: Sounds about right. What field of math, or what topic of math is this? I would like to dive deeper into that topic matter but I am lacking the required vocabulary to find a starting point.

Comment: Combinatorics is the field of mathematics about counting. Like counting all possible ways that a given property can be satisfied.

Comment: Statistics is the field of mathematics about the effects of transformations on a random variable. Like what happens on average to a sample of random numbers as my sample size in grows? Or how much worse (in probability) is the sample median capable of estimating the population mean than the sample mean?

Comment: Measure theory is the field of mathematics that establishes the validity and usage of the words "probability" and "random variable".

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned using computer simulation, I assume your sets are finite.

The last condition you have does not give any information, since for any sets we have
$$
| A \cup B | + | A \cap B | = | A | + | B | 
$$ so your inequality is trivial and you don't have any information about sets relation at all. The best you can do is to bound
$$ \max\left\{\max_{i \leq 6}|A_i|, X - \sum_{i=7}^n|A_i|\right\}\leq|\bigcup_{i = 1}^6 A_i|\leq \min\left\{\sum_{i =1}^6|A_i|, X\right\}.
$$

If $n > 6$ you can easily find examples which show that those bounds are the best you can get.

Comment: Yes, my sets are finite. The last condition does add the information that there may be intersections between sets. The answer to my question would be trivial if $|A_x| + |A_y| = |A_x \cup A_y|$.

Comment: That does not add information, since you always have $|A_x| + |A_y| \geq |A_x \cup A_y|$. If you had $|A_x| + |A_y| = |A_x \cup A_y|$ or $|A_x| + |A_y| > |A_x \cup A_y|$ that would be some information